# ProjectServer 2013 REST API - Creating Tasks

Tags: rest, office365, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

I'm playing with ProjectOnline and trying to use REST APIs to create projects and tasks etc. I have managed to add a project using following REST call

```
https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects/Add
```

However when I try to add Task or a Resource to the created project it gives me error "Cannot find resource for the request Add". Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

My REST call is this

```
https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('<project ID>')/Tasks/Add
```

The project ID is the ID of the Project created using the REST call 1.

Comment: Are you trying this programmatically or you just hit the url from browser?

Comment: I'm using the POSTMAN Rest client to send rest calls

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are calling the PublishedProject resource add not the DraftProject resource, your URL needs to be something like this:

```
/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('projectid')/Draft/Tasks/add(parameters)
```

The Draft section being key here.

HTH,
Martin